# What Is liboainject

Tags: xcode, xcode-instruments

When I profile my iOS app using instruments / allocations and hide system libraries, liboainject.dylib is also displayed. I stop instruments and select File/Symbols. liboainject.dylib is displayed next to a yellow-colored dot. The binary path for liboainject.dylib is:

/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/liboainject.dylib

When I tap the UIButtond entitled "Locate" next to SYM Path, the finder moves to the LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard files for the app. Is it normal to see liboainject.dylib at the above path? What is liboainject.dylib?